# 3D rigid body physics engine

Tags: packages, physics, interoperability

Is there a package in Mathematica that will allow me to simulate collisions of 3d rigid bodies?

If not, what known libraries could I use and how?

For example, one problem I want to simulate is a coin toss. I would need to specify an infinite plane, a cylinder with an initial linear and angular momentum, and properties like friction and restitution. After running the simulation I would want to check (no need for graphics here) if it landed head or tails (or side).

As I said, I don't need the simulation to show graphics.

Edit:
Someone mentioned UnityLink. Any resources about getting started will be appreciated!

Comment: We'll need a bit more info... Are you interested in collisions? In forces between the bodies? Vibrations? What kind of problem are you trying to solve?

Comment: @b3m2a1 For now, I'm interested in collisions. Also I'm interested in simulating cubes, spheres, cilynders.

Comment: There is no built-in physics engine, unfortunately.

Comment: @C.E. does Unity have such a thing? There's now UnityLink which would make it easy to work with theirs.

Comment: @b3m2a1 Yes, it almost certainly has to have it and I considered mentioning it, but I suspect you also have to learn a decent amount about Unity before you can use it.

Comment: @C.E. True but if the OP wants to invest the time I bet it’d pay off.

Comment: @b3m2a1 Any suggestions on how to get started with that?

Comment: @Ivan Did you already go through the UnityLink getting started tutorial that's in the documentation?

Comment: UnityLink Getting Started guide: https://reference.wolfram.com/language/UnityLink/guide/GettingStarted.html  Root of UnityLink documents tree: https://reference.wolfram.com/language/UnityLink/guide/CallingUnityFromTheWolframLanguage.html

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Since this answer was originally posted, the Blender software package has undergone significant revision causing the Python scripts to break. I have modified the scripts so that they should work from v2.79b to v2.93LTS.

## Updated Blender scripts

Note: I added an update below to import position and orientation transformations and view the 3D simulation results in *Mathematica*.

I have used the free program [*Blender* v2.79b](https://www.blender.org/) to simulate the handling of 100s of complex shapes through a geometrically complex industrial machine with many moving parts including vibrating elements.  So, it should be able to handle a "coin flip".  I believe *Blender* still uses the [*Bullet Physics Engine*](https://github.com/bulletphysics/bullet3) as its solver.  I should warn you that collision simulation can get difficult and that there are a lot of tricks of the trade you must learn to be accurate and fast in a general case.

*Blender* has a python interface and it can be run as a background task (*Bullet* also has a python interface, but I am not familiar with its operation).  Since *Mathematica* can create text files with *StringTemplate* and can execute system commands, we should be able to create a python script to drive a *Blender* simulation.

## Python Script Generation

*Blender* has a fairly well-documented API and there many resources one can find online to generate python script.

```
import bpy
from math import pi

# Read current Blender version
version = bpy.app.version

for o in bpy.data.objects:
    if version < (2, 80, 0):
        if o.type == 'MESH' or o.type == 'EMPTY':
            o.select = True
        else:
            o.select = False
    else:
        o.select_set(o.type == 'EMPTY' or o.type == 'MESH')

# Delete all objects in the scene
bpy.ops.object.delete()

# Add the floor
if version < (2, 80, 0):
    bpy.ops.mesh.primitive_cube_add(radius=5, location=(0, 0, 0))
else:
    bpy.ops.mesh.primitive_cube_add(size=10, location=(0, 0, 0))
bpy.ops.transform.resize(value=(1, 1, 0.1))
bpy.ops.rigidbody.objects_add(type='PASSIVE')
boxObj = bpy.context.active_object
boxObj.rigid_body.collision_shape = "BOX"
boxObj.name = "Ground"

# Add the Coin
bpy.ops.mesh.primitive_cylinder_add(radius=1, depth=0.1, location=(0, 0, 3))
bpy.ops.rigidbody.objects_add(type='ACTIVE')
boxObj = bpy.context.active_object
boxObj.rigid_body.collision_shape = "CYLINDER"
bpy.context.object.rigid_body.friction = 0.25
bpy.context.object.rigid_body.restitution = 0.75
boxObj.name = "Coin"
# Set reference to the coin
coin = bpy.data.objects["Coin"]

# Set a reference to the scene
sce = bpy.context.scene
# Set first frame
sce.frame_set(1)
# Set Keyframes
coin.keyframe_insert(data_path="location")
coin.keyframe_insert(data_path="rotation_euler")
bpy.context.object.rigid_body.kinematic = True
bpy.context.object.keyframe_insert('rigid_body.kinematic')

# Advance two frames and add translational and rotational motion
sce.frame_set(4)
# Translate up a little
coin.location.z = 3.45
# Rotate coin predominantly around the x-axis
coin.rotation_euler.x = 1
coin.rotation_euler.y = 0.1
coin.rotation_euler.z = 0.1
# Set Keyframes
coin.keyframe_insert(data_path="location")
coin.keyframe_insert(data_path="rotation_euler")
bpy.context.object.rigid_body.kinematic = False
bpy.context.object.keyframe_insert('rigid_body.kinematic')

# Set frame to the end
sce.frame_set(250)

# Bake rigid body simulation
override = {'scene': bpy.context.scene,
            'point_cache': bpy.context.scene.rigidbody_world.point_cache}
# bake to current frame
bpy.ops.ptcache.bake(override, bake=False)

# Get transformations
tr = coin.matrix_world.translation
eu = coin.matrix_world.to_euler()
print("          X                  Y                  Z                  RX                  RY                  RZ")
print(tr.x, tr.y, tr.z, eu.x, eu.y, eu.z)

if eu.x > pi / 2.:
    print("Coin is heads")
else:
    print("Coin is tails")
```

The script above does is the following:

1. Selects and deletes all extraneous objects in the scene.
2. Adds a passive cube (note that cubes are better than planes for collisions) for the ground.
3. Adds an active cylindrical coin.

   - Sets friction to 0.25
   - Sets restitution to 0.75
4. Adds keyframe animate to set initial velocity and rotation.
5. Prints out and tests if coin has rotated more than $\frac{\pi}{2}$ radians to determine heads/tails.

## Driving from *Mathematica*

We can create a parametric model in *Mathematica* by replacing hard coded parameters with template variables using `` delimiters as in the *createCoinFlip* function.

```
createCoinFlip[z_, rx_, ry_, rz_, friction_, restitution_] := 
 StringTemplate["import bpy
from math import pi

# Read current Blender version
version = bpy.app.version

for o in bpy.data.objects:
    if version < (2, 80, 0):
        if o.type == 'MESH' or o.type == 'EMPTY':
            o.select = True
        else:
            o.select = False
    else:
        o.select_set(o.type == 'EMPTY' or o.type == 'MESH')

# Delete all objects in the scene
bpy.ops.object.delete()

# Add the floor
if version < (2, 80, 0):
    bpy.ops.mesh.primitive_cube_add(radius=5, location=(0, 0, 0))
else:
    bpy.ops.mesh.primitive_cube_add(size=10, location=(0, 0, 0))
bpy.ops.transform.resize(value=(1, 1, 0.1))
bpy.ops.rigidbody.objects_add(type='PASSIVE')
boxObj = bpy.context.active_object
boxObj.rigid_body.collision_shape = \"BOX\"
boxObj.name = \"Ground\"

# Add the Coin
bpy.ops.mesh.primitive_cylinder_add(radius=1, depth=0.1, \
location=(0, 0, 3))
bpy.ops.rigidbody.objects_add(type='ACTIVE')
boxObj = bpy.context.active_object
boxObj.rigid_body.collision_shape = \"CYLINDER\"
bpy.context.object.rigid_body.friction = `friction`
bpy.context.object.rigid_body.restitution = `restitution`
boxObj.name = \"Coin\"
# Set reference to the coin
coin = bpy.data.objects[\"Coin\"]

# Set a reference to the scene
sce = bpy.context.scene
# Set first frame
sce.frame_set(1)
# Set Keyframes
coin.keyframe_insert(data_path=\"location\")
coin.keyframe_insert(data_path=\"rotation_euler\")
bpy.context.object.rigid_body.kinematic = True
bpy.context.object.keyframe_insert('rigid_body.kinematic')

# Advance two frames and add translational and rotational motion
sce.frame_set(4)
# Translate up a little
coin.location.z = `z`
# Rotate coin predominantly around the x-axis
coin.rotation_euler.x = `rx`
coin.rotation_euler.y = `ry`
coin.rotation_euler.z = `rz`
# Set Keyframes
coin.keyframe_insert(data_path=\"location\")
coin.keyframe_insert(data_path=\"rotation_euler\")
bpy.context.object.rigid_body.kinematic = False
bpy.context.object.keyframe_insert('rigid_body.kinematic')

# Set frame to the end
sce.frame_set(250)

# Bake rigid body simulation
override = {'scene': bpy.context.scene,
            'point_cache': \
bpy.context.scene.rigidbody_world.point_cache}
# bake to current frame
bpy.ops.ptcache.bake(override, bake=False)

# Get transformations
tr = coin.matrix_world.translation
eu = coin.matrix_world.to_euler()
print(\"\
          X                  Y                  Z                  RX                  R\
Y                  RZ\")
print(tr.x, tr.y, tr.z, eu.x, eu.y, eu.z)

if eu.x > pi / 2.:
    print(\"Coin flip result is heads\")
else:
    print(\"Coin flip result is tails\")
"][<|"z" -> z, "rx" -> rx, "ry" -> ry, "rz" -> rz, 
"friction" -> friction, "restitution" -> restitution|>]
```

*Blender* will send a lot of information to standard out.  We can parse this output with *Find* to extract a line of interest.  Putting it all together, the following will create a python script, run *Blender* in the background, and parse the output.

```
fileName = "coinflip.py";
file = OpenWrite[fileName];
WriteString[file, createCoinFlip[3.95, 1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.25, 0.75]];
Close[file];
outputfile = CreateFile[];
Run["blender --background --python coinflip.py >>" <> outputfile];
stext = OpenRead[outputfile];
Find[stext, "Coin"]
Close[stext];
DeleteFile[outputfile]
(* Coin is tails *)
```

You can visualize the results of the simulation by removing the "--background" and repeating the step above.

```
fileName = "coinflip.py";
file = OpenWrite[fileName];
WriteString[file, createCoinFlip[3.45, 1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.25, 0.75]];
Close[file];
outputfile = CreateFile[];
Run["blender --python coinflip.py >>" <> outputfile];
stext = OpenRead[outputfile];
Find[stext, "Coin"]
Close[stext];
DeleteFile[outputfile]
```

If you left click anywhere on the screen and hit the play button, then you should see the following:

[image: Blender Coin Flip]

## Rendering in *Blender*

You can take advantage of *Blender's* photorealistic rendering capability to create a nice animation if desired.

[image: Rendered Coin Flip]

## Update: Additional Post Processing in *Mathematica*

*Blender* is geared more towards the artist whereas *Mathematica* is geared more towards the physicist.  We can find synergy when we combine the strengths of both tools.

What follows is a simple example of how to conduct additional post-processing on a *Blender* simulation in *Mathematica*.

First, let's modify the python generation script to give the positions and orientations of the coin at each frame (we will insert a string "PosRot" to identify the appropriate lines).

```
createCoinFlipTransform[z_, rx_, ry_, rz_, friction_, restitution_] :=
  StringTemplate["import bpy
from math import pi

# Read current Blender version
version = bpy.app.version

for o in bpy.data.objects:
    if version < (2, 80, 0):
        if o.type == 'MESH' or o.type == 'EMPTY':
            o.select = True
        else:
            o.select = False
    else:
        o.select_set(o.type == 'EMPTY' or o.type == 'MESH')

# Delete all objects in the scene
bpy.ops.object.delete()

# Add the floor
if version < (2, 80, 0):
    bpy.ops.mesh.primitive_cube_add(radius=5, location=(0, 0, 0))
else:
    bpy.ops.mesh.primitive_cube_add(size=10, location=(0, 0, 0))
bpy.ops.transform.resize(value=(1, 1, 0.1))
bpy.ops.rigidbody.objects_add(type='PASSIVE')
boxObj = bpy.context.active_object
boxObj.rigid_body.collision_shape = \"BOX\"
boxObj.name = \"Ground\"

# Add the Coin
bpy.ops.mesh.primitive_cylinder_add(radius=1, depth=0.1, \
location=(0, 0, 3))
bpy.ops.rigidbody.objects_add(type='ACTIVE')
cylObj = bpy.context.active_object
cylObj.rigid_body.collision_shape = \"CYLINDER\"
bpy.context.object.rigid_body.friction = `friction`
bpy.context.object.rigid_body.restitution = `restitution`
cylObj.name = \"Coin\"
# Set reference to the coin
coin = bpy.data.objects[\"Coin\"]

# Set a reference to the scene
sce = bpy.context.scene
# Set first frame
sce.frame_set(1)
# Set Keyframes
coin.keyframe_insert(data_path=\"location\")
coin.keyframe_insert(data_path=\"rotation_euler\")
bpy.context.object.rigid_body.kinematic = True
bpy.context.object.keyframe_insert('rigid_body.kinematic')

# Advance two frames and add translational and rotational motion
sce.frame_set(4)
# Translate up a little
coin.location.z = `z`
# Rotate coin predominantly around the x-axis
coin.rotation_euler.x = `rx`
coin.rotation_euler.y = `ry`
coin.rotation_euler.z = `rz`
# Set Keyframes
coin.keyframe_insert(data_path=\"location\")
coin.keyframe_insert(data_path=\"rotation_euler\")
bpy.context.object.rigid_body.kinematic = False
bpy.context.object.keyframe_insert('rigid_body.kinematic')

# Set frame to the end
sce.frame_set(250)

# Bake rigid body simulation
override = {'scene': bpy.context.scene,
            'point_cache': \
bpy.context.scene.rigidbody_world.point_cache}
# bake to current frame
bpy.ops.ptcache.bake(override, bake=False)

# Get transformations
tr = coin.matrix_world.translation
eu = coin.matrix_world.to_euler()

for i in range(250):
    sce.frame_set(i)
    tr = coin.matrix_world.translation
    eu = coin.matrix_world.to_euler()
    print(\"PosRot\",tr.x, tr.y, tr.z, eu.x , eu.y , eu.z )
"][<|"z" -> z, "rx" -> rx, "ry" -> ry, "rz" -> rz, 
"friction" -> friction, "restitution" -> restitution|>]
```

We can extract the positions and orientations of the simulation with the following code.

```
fileName = "coinflip.py";
file = OpenWrite[fileName];
WriteString[file, createCoinFlipTransform[4, -Pi 0.75, 0.1, 0.1, 0.25, 0.75]];
Close[file];
outputfile = CreateFile[];
Run["blender --background --python coinflip.py >>" <> outputfile];
stext = OpenRead[outputfile];
data = ToExpression@StringSplit[#] & /@ FindList[stext, "PosRot"];
{tx, ty, tz, rx, ry, rz} = Transpose@data[[All, {2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7}]];
Close[stext];
DeleteFile[outputfile]
```

We can define a cuboid and cylinder that have the same dimensions as the *Blender* simulation and we can create a transformation function with the following code.

```
box = {Cuboid[{-5, -5, -0.5}, {5, 5, 0.5}]};
cyl = {Cylinder[{{0, 0, -0.05}, {0, 0, 0.05}}, 1], 
   AbsolutePointSize[10], 
   Opacity[1], {Black, Point[{0, 0, 0}]}, {Red, 
    Point[{1, 0, 0}]}, {Green, Point[{0, 1, 0}]}, {Blue, 
    Point[{0, 0, 1}]}};
m = IdentityMatrix[4];
m[[1 ;; 3, 1 ;; 3]] = EulerMatrix[{a, b, c}, {1, 2, 3}];
m[[1 ;; 3, -1]] = {x, y, z};
transform[a_, b_, c_, x_, y_, z_] = TransformationFunction[m];
```

Now, we can combine plots of position and orientation (or other quantities like angular momentum) into a Manipulate[] function.

```
Manipulate[
 Column[{Row[{ListPlot[{tx[[1 ;; i]], ty[[1 ;; i]], tz[[1 ;; i]]}, 
      Filling -> Axis, ImageSize -> {200, 200}, PlotRange -> All, 
      PlotLegends -> {"tx", "ty", "tz"}],
     ListPlot[{rx[[1 ;; i]], ry[[1 ;; i]], rz[[1 ;; i]]}, 
      Filling -> Axis, ImageSize -> {200, 200}, PlotRange -> All, 
      PlotLegends -> {"rx", "ry", "rz"}]}], 
   Graphics3D[{{Opacity[0.75], Red, box}, 
     GeometricTransformation[{Opacity[.85], Yellow, cyl}, 
      transform[rx[[i]], ry[[i]], rz[[i]], tx[[i]], ty[[i]], 
       tz[[i]]]]}, SphericalRegion -> True,  Boxed -> False, 
    ImageSize -> {400, 400}]}], {i, 1, 250, 1}]
```

[image: Physics Graphs and 3D Animation]

Comment: Thank you very much! this answer is great! One thing: At first, running a copy of the code you posted I got an error in cmd about some "Unexpected indent". I don't know if it's something to do with how text is formatted on stackexchange, but I did fix it!

Comment: I was having a little trouble getting the markdown to work here.  You have SE, Mathematica, Python, and Windows all needing to escape their notion of special characters.  I am glad you found it useful.  I will take a look at the post tomorrow to see if I can repeat the error and try to rectify.

Comment: @Ivan I fixed the indentation problem.  The "Code Sample" or ctrl-K in SE adds extra preceding spaces in the MMA code string, which causes a problem, because Python is sensitive to indentation.  This is an artifact of trying to highlight a MMA code that produces a Python code in SE.