# Define a function on a MeshRegion

Tags: function-construction, finite-element-method, interpolation, geometry, mesh

This looks like a simple question with the answer to be easily found, but unfortunately I could not find it either on the web or in the documentation browser.

Let us assume we have a MeshRegion `meshx` with vertices `vlis = MeshCoordinates[meshx]`.

So `vlis` is a list of 2D points (in my case). Suppose I have a second list `fvlis`
of the same length containing real numbers (to fix ideas, could be vectors too). Then fvlis defines on `meshx` a piecewise linear function `f[x,y]` (written in Mathematica notation). The function should be defined for all points that are in the region of `meshx`.

Now the problem is: How can I actually get this function `f[x,y]`? Is there a simple inbuilt function for this, or is it necessary to write a piece of code for it? If the latter, how could one do it?

Comment: Should `f[x, y]` only be defined on the mesh vertices, and therefore return unevaluated for other values of $(x,y)$, or do you want an `Interpolation`?

Comment: @MarcoB I want a (piecewise linear, for example) interpolation. (I edited the post for clarification).

Comment: Then `Interpolation[Transpose[{vlis, fvlis}]` should work

Comment: Perhaps `ElementMeshInterpolation[]` is what you are looking for

Comment: @Ulrich Neumann The solution with`Interpolation` worked for me, but of course it is always good to have several tools at hand. What could be the advantages of `ElementMeshInterpolation`? Is it faster?

Comment: @MarcoB Thanks a lot, it worked beautifully and I could create my sought after graphics with it - seems I have still to learn much about Mathematica (but its only three days that I am using it, so perhaps I can be exculpated).

Comment: @JürgenBöhm Yes it is faster and not necessary piecewise linear

Comment: @Jürgen Perhaps you could write a self-answer to summarize the comments then? It is always preferable to have answered questions, and self-answers are encouraged on this forum.

Answer (score 2):

I used the hints in the comments to write the following code (excerpt from my notebook):

[image]

With a little more calculation this allowed me to generate:

[image]

Explanation: `result.off` is a flat image of `quartic-R11.off`, a so called (conformal) surface mesh parametrization. I computed this externally with

[CGAL Planar Parameterization of triangulated surface meshes](https://doc.cgal.org/latest/Surface_mesh_parameterization/index.html#Chapter_Planar_Parameterization_of_Triangulated_Surface_Meshes)

The vertices in `meshx` and `workMesh`correspond to each other in their respective sequential orders. The map `phiMap1` is the final map that parameterizes `workMesh` as the image of `meshx2d`.

In a part of the calculation not shown, I generated a rectangular array of grid points over `meshx2d` and projected them with `phiMap1` onto the quartic surface. For each of the image points I subtracted a ball of suitable radius from the quartic surface. This gave me a multiply punctured surface, where the holes are placed (in my eyes) in an aesthetically pleasing way.

Of course there is still much to improve and room for further experimentation, but it was a successfull first step.

Comment: Thank you for putting together this answer! Please include the code snippets as formatted text rather than just as images.

Comment: @MarcoB Is there a special Mathematica menu point to export selected cells as text or does one do simply copy and paste (with the system clipboard)?

Comment: In most cases copy/paste is fine, but take a look at the suggestions here: [How to copy code from Mathematica so it looks good on this site](https://mathematica.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1584/27951).

Comment: Click on the blue circle-i for more information on how to fix the issue mentioned in the message.

Comment: Unfortunately, you did not provide the code for your answer, but I have made something similar for your other question [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/278503/18437)