# How to run Python script with an argument?

Tags: python

I want to run Python script with argument 'arg'

```
  > python app.py arg
```

Without 'arg' it works like

```
 session = StartExternalSession["Python"];
 ExternalEvaluate[session, File["app.py"]];
```

but I don't understend how to add 'arg'.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have many many python environments on my computer and I was never able to get my ExternalEvaluator to recognize.  My workaround is to just use a shell command.  If your app just returns values, it may work well enough.  For example, my [rigid body physics answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/195649/61809) was driven from *Mathematica*, but the heavy lifting was done with Blender's python. If your app is interactive, this answer is not for you.

If we copy the prog.py example from [Python's argparse](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/argparse.html), then we can execute a simple shell command.  Here is the python listing:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# prog.py
import argparse

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description='Process some integers.')
parser.add_argument('integers', metavar='N', type=int, nargs='+',
                    help='an integer for the accumulator')
parser.add_argument('--sum', dest='accumulate', action='store_const',
                    const=sum, default=max,
                    help='sum the integers (default: find the max)')

args = parser.parse_args()

print(args.accumulate(args.integers))
```

Here is one way using [`Run`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Run.html):

```
SetDirectory[NotebookDirectory[]];
outputfile = CreateFile[];
Run["C:\\Users\\Tim\\Anaconda2\\envs\\env37\\python prog.py 1 2 3 4 \
--sum >>" <> outputfile];
stext = OpenRead[outputfile];
Read[stext, Number]
DeleteFile[outputfile];
(* 10 *)
```

Here is an alternative way using [`RunProcess`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/RunProcess.html):

```
SetDirectory[NotebookDirectory[]];
RunProcess[{"C:\\Users\\Tim\\Anaconda2\\envs\\env37\\python", 
   "prog.py", "--sum", "1", "2", "3", "4"}]["StandardOutput"]
(* "10" *)
```

## Update in response to comment

The code in comment, `Run["c:\\test\\python app.py --sum >> out2"]` , returns an error because it is expecting a list of space delimited arguments.  `RunProcess` gives more insight to the problem.  For example:

```
SetDirectory[NotebookDirectory[]];
RunProcess[{"C:\\Users\\Tim\\Anaconda2\\envs\\env37\\python", 
  "prog.py", "--sum"}]
(* <|"ExitCode" -> 2, "StandardOutput" -> "", 
 "StandardError" -> "usage: prog.py [-h] [--sum] N [N ...]
  
  prog.py: error: the following arguments are required: N
  
  "|> *)
```

Exit code 0 means the code successfully executed.  Non-zero exit code does not send the output to standard out, but to standard error.  Standard error shows that there is a usage error requesting at least 1 numerical argument.

Comment: I try simply to run **Run["c:\\test\\python app.py --sum >> out2"]** and it doen't work.

Comment: @RodionStepanov I have an extended comment in the update.  If you are using the same example, you need at least one numerical argument or it throws an error.  `RunProcess` will give you more outputs as an association to help troubleshoot the issues.

Comment: I've got error `RunProcess::pnfd: Program c:\test\python not found.  Check Environment["PATH"]` 
I understand that it is necessary to configure the environment. It's complicated. It would be nice  go back to `ExternalEvaluate [session, File ["app.py"]];`

Comment: @RodionStepanov If you provide a fully qualified path to python, you should not need to specify it in %PATH%.  Does python launch in a command shell (cmd) if you type "c:\test\python"?.  I was able to launch an ANSYS python that was not in the Path by providing the fully qualified path `RunProcess[{"C:\\Program Files\\ANSYS \
Inc\\v201\\CEI\\bin\\cpython.bat", "prog.py", "--sum"}]`.

Comment: If I type "c:\test\python" then python deas not lunch. But simply "python" works. So I run `RunProcess[{"python", "app.py", "arg"}]` and it works now! Thank you.